# Riddle Reorganized

Tags: riddle, word

The word I seek is split into letters,
each letter enclosed in a riddle below.
Each riddle will get harder as the number increases.
You know the length of my word, but what's the word?
One letter wrong is likely to change the whole word!

Letter #1:

*At the cross roads,*
*there's a twist down one path*
*and dead ends the rest.*
*there's one of me on every line*

Letter #2:

*You will be female without me,*
*But if I come I will let you walk out of here alive*
*I split to make a number of relevance to me*

Letter #3:

*With me you are will gain wisdom*
*But if you think you know it all your eyes will never see knowledge*
*Don't ditch me - I am as good as two of you*

Letter #4:

*The English language just wouldn't be the same without me*
*In the name of Englishmen, I present them all*
*And lag behind to help them with their language*

Letter #5:

*I am cousin of the square, though he be twice as large as me*
*Though I got half the score of my friend 'I' in my degree°*
*Lover of me or loather of me, this oath is over*

What word am I and what does each riddle mean?

**EDIT**

Seeing as no-one of yet has letter #2, I'll put some emphasis on it:

```
OLD
```

*You will be female without me,*
*But if I come I will let you walk out of here alive*
*I split to make a number of relevance to me*

```
NEW
```

*You will be female without me,*
*But if I come I will let you **walk** out of here alive*
*I **double** to make a number of relevance to me*
***In a chart of chemistry***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A guess that the answer is

> Towel

Letter #1:

At the cross roads,
there's a twist down one path
and dead ends the rest.
there's one of me on every line

> **T** - A lower case t has three "dead ends" and one curved path.  There are t's in each line of this micro-riddle.

Letter #2:

You will be female without me,
But if I come I will let you **walk** out of here alive
I **double** to make a number of relevance to me
**In a chart of chemistry**

> **O** I honestly thought this was playing on the Y chromosome, as far as I know TYWEL is not a word.  **EDIT**: Here's a try anyway... Bisecting an O with a line results in this Ø, which is the symbol for diameter.  An o is a circle, so a diameter would be important to the letter o. *This isn't it, but it was interesting and close enough for me to want to leave it in.*

The Edits I think are correct:

> **NEW EDIT**: I can only figure out part of the clue for #2, but O is the symbol for the element Oxygen, and its atomic number is 8, which can be made from two O's. **AH- The Final Piece**: SHE/SHOE, she being female (when O is removed) and a shoe letting you walk away.  Major credit goes to Daphne B who cracked it while I was weekending away from the computer, but left the breadcrumbs for me to follow.

Letter #3:

With me you are will gain wisdom
But if you think you know it all your eyes will never see knowledge
Don't ditch me - I am as good as two of you

> **W** - With a w you can spell wisdom, you can't spell knowledge without one, and it is literally two u's.

Letter #4:

The English language just wouldn't be the same without me
In the name of Englishmen, I present them all
And lag behind to help them with their language

> **E** - English starts with an e, and language ends with one.

Letter #5:

I am cousin of the square, though he be twice as large as me
Though I got half the score of my friend 'I' in my degree°
Lover of me or loather of me, this oath is over

> **L** - Two l's could be made into a square if one is rotated.  I is a line of 180°, while an L has a 90° angle.  L's are also in lover and loather.

Comment: Try and get Letter#2

Comment: I'll accept then

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil Thanks, I'm working on it.  But geez, I feel like I'm back high school again- I can't get my mind on anything but *the big O*.

Comment: Maybe the clue is referring to the similarity in shape to a certain piece of anatomy?

Comment: @Irishpanda That's the slippery slope I'm on the edge of right now.  If my edit doesn't turn up any results, then I'll get ready to slide on down, into the gutter, if necessary.

Comment: You don't think it might have something to do with...linguistic gender?

Comment: sorry still no - this is a sort of anagram

Comment: "You" without "o" is "Yu", which can apparently (https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090630085429AAerLjR) be a female name.

Comment: So the "walking" clue and the "female" clue are related.  If you remove the letter (which is O) from the middle of the thing-related-to-walking, you get the thing-that-means-female.  I didn't want to post a whole answer since you did most of the work.

Comment: @DaphneB you are very right. raisinghellyer is right about the last line though

Comment: @DaphneB I think I got it now.  Thanks for the tip and for keeping the vultures from circling around this; it was truly a noble deed.

Comment: Congratulations, I knew you'd get it

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil Thanks.  It was definitely one of those "duh" moments once I got it, but a joyous one, not a frustrated one.  That means it was well put together, nice and simple, but clever.

Answer (score 3):

I only (think I) know two letters, but that's enough for a partial answer.

Letter #1:

> t - the bend is at the bottom where the t curves in this font, the dead ends are the top and left/right.  Each line of this section of the clue (for that matter, all the italicized sections) has a "t".

Letter #3:

> w - with me you get "w"isdom because it begins with a w, and also w = double you = "as good as two of you"

Comment: Good so far :) Keep going

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer here to add to the previous:

Letter #4:

> E 
>  The English language starts with E, so definitely would be different without it.  Also, when at the end of the word (when it "lags behind", the letter e changes how you pronounce other vowels in the sentence (e.g., hat vs. hate)

Letter #5:

> L
>  Capital L is roughly half a square. A straight line (l) could be said to have a 180 degree angle while a capital L has a 90 degree angle. Add L to over to get Lover, add L to oath to get Loath (similar to loather).

Comment: Good again, not quite with the second half of Letter #4

Answer (score 1):

Building on the other answers:

> Towel

Comment: you must give me the reason for Letter#2 before I can accept.

Comment: You are right though

Comment: in portuguese, masculine words have O as the definite article. therefore all words would be feminine without it

Comment: sorry no - i'll edit the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: towel.

Reasoning for clue 2: 'Her' is female without 'o'. With it, becomes 'hero'. Not sure about the third line.

Comment: A hero can be a female.

Comment: No - sorry your on the right track.

Comment: @PythonMaster Eh..heroine is female, not hero..